# Determine the total value of a frequency table

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataset in which the number of pixels is counted for each value looking like this:

```
      HISTO_2 HISTO_3 HISTO_4 HISTO_5 HISTO_6 HISTO_7 HISTO_10 HISTO_11 HISTO_14 HISTO_18  HISTO_19 HISTO_23
1        0     390     652     157      32       7       0       0        0        0        0        0
2        0      22      41      27      23      11       8       5        4       11        2        4
3        0     916     671     167      40       7       4       5        2        1        2        2
4        0    2600     810     172      38       0       0       0        0        0        0        0
5        0     110     987     791     248      59      11       5        0        1        0        0
6        0     778     808     182      43       5       0       0        0        0        0        0
7        0    1095     846     199      55      12       8       3        0        0        0        0
8        0    1045     545      60       0       0       0       0        0        0        0        0
9        0     868     422      92       2       0       0       0        0        0        0        0
10       0    1225     597     160      57      27       0       0        0        0        0        0
11       0    1092    1096     635     150      33       0       0        0        0        0        0
```

*HISTO_2* caputres the number of pixels with value *2*, *HISTO_3* caputres the number of pixels with value *3* and so on. I need to find a way that enables me to efficiently count the **total value** of all pixels per row. Precisely, each value of the column *HISTO_3* must be multiplied by three, and each value of the column *HISTO_$4* must be multiplied by 4 and so on... before rowise sums can be calculated. This has to be done for ten datasets. As can be seen in the table, the value of the columns doesn't follow a balanced sequence and for each dataset, the sequence can be different.

Any efficient solutions to my problem?
PS: If you come up better title for my question, feel free to edit :)

Comment: you can use `df %>% mutate(freq=rowSums(across(starts_with('HIST'))))`

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr` (for `unnest_wider`)

EDIT: First extracting the values for multiplication from the variable names, then `unnest`ing the list to enable multiplication by across block.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(mult = list(as.numeric(sub(".*_(\\d+)$", "\\1", colnames(.))))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(mult, names_sep="_") %>% 
  summarize(across(starts_with("HIST")) * across(starts_with("mult"))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(c_across(everything()))) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 11 × 13
   HISTO_2 HISTO_3 HISTO_4 HISTO_5 HISTO_6 HISTO_7 HISTO_10 HISTO_11 HISTO_14
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1       0    1170    2608     785     192      49        0        0        0
 2       0      66     164     135     138      77       80       55       56
 3       0    2748    2684     835     240      49       40       55       28
 4       0    7800    3240     860     228       0        0        0        0
 5       0     330    3948    3955    1488     413      110       55        0
 6       0    2334    3232     910     258      35        0        0        0
 7       0    3285    3384     995     330      84       80       33        0
 8       0    3135    2180     300       0       0        0        0        0
 9       0    2604    1688     460      12       0        0        0        0
10       0    3675    2388     800     342     189        0        0        0
11       0    3276    4384    3175     900     231        0        0        0
   HISTO_18 HISTO_19 HISTO_23 total
      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1        0        0        0  4804
 2      198       38       92  1099
 3       18       38       46  6781
 4        0        0        0 12128
 5       18        0        0 10317
 6        0        0        0  6769
 7        0        0        0  8191
 8        0        0        0  5615
 9        0        0        0  4764
10        0        0        0  7394
11        0        0        0 11966
```

For all 10 data sets

```
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10)

lapply(df_list ,function(x)
  x %>% 
    mutate(mult = list(as.numeric(sub(".*_(\\d+)$", "\\1", colnames(.))))) %>% 
    unnest_wider(mult, names_sep="_") %>% 
    summarize(across(starts_with("HIST")) * across(starts_with("mult"))) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(total = sum(c_across(everything()))) %>% 
    ungroup())
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(HISTO_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), HISTO_3 = c(390L, 22L, 916L, 2600L, 110L, 778L, 1095L, 
1045L, 868L, 1225L, 1092L), HISTO_4 = c(652L, 41L, 671L, 810L, 
987L, 808L, 846L, 545L, 422L, 597L, 1096L), HISTO_5 = c(157L, 
27L, 167L, 172L, 791L, 182L, 199L, 60L, 92L, 160L, 635L), HISTO_6 = c(32L, 
23L, 40L, 38L, 248L, 43L, 55L, 0L, 2L, 57L, 150L), HISTO_7 = c(7L, 
11L, 7L, 0L, 59L, 5L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 27L, 33L), HISTO_10 = c(0L, 
8L, 4L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), HISTO_11 = c(0L, 5L, 
5L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), HISTO_14 = c(0L, 4L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), HISTO_18 = c(0L, 11L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), HISTO_19 = c(0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), HISTO_23 = c(0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is wrong as I am looking for the total value of pixels per row. Meaning that e.g. the the row each value in HISTO_3 must be multiplied by 3. I will edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: @LucasLeonhard Made some changes, should now work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in the TOTAL VALUE of the row pixels, you could do:

Base R:

```
colSums(t(df) * as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '',names(df))))
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11 
 4804  1099  6781 12128 10317  6769  8191  5615  4764  7394 11966
```

or even:

```
as.matrix(df)%*%as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '',names(df)))
    [,1]
1   4804
2   1099
3   6781
4  12128
5  10317
6   6769
7   8191
8   5615
9   4764
10  7394
11 11966
```

if you are unfamiliar with `gsub` and `\\D` ie regex, then use

```
library(readr)
as.matrix(df) %*% parse_number(names(df))
    [,1]
1   4804
2   1099
3   6781
4  12128
5  10317
6   6769
7   8191
8   5615
9   4764
10  7394
11 11966
```